# Cortex-M7 (M4) SVCall from another ISR: executes when SVCall has higher priority, straight to the HardFault otherwise

Tags: arm, embedded, interrupt, cortex-m

Context: writing an RTOS, have a working scheduler, context switcher, etc. Implementing SVCall now. Main test/dev platform is STM32F746-Disco Cortex-M7, also works on STM32F469 disco with Cortex-M4.

My goal is to set SVCall to pending, finish the current interrupt and tail-chain into SVC handler. I do this interrupt cascading in a pair of places as it has peculiar use in my implementation (for example, naked interrupt handler preserves registers of thread and then software-triggers another ISR where I can do full complex C code).

If I `__asm volatile("SVC 0");` from thread, it works correctly.

If I `__asm volatile("SVC 0");` from ISR, whose priority is lower than SVC priority, it works correctly.

If I `__asm volatile("SVC 0");` from ISR, whose priority is higher than SVC priority, SVC instruction falls straight to HardFault immediately. It doesn't enter the SVC handler, it doesn't even finish the current higher priority handler.

This interrupt cascading (as I call it) approach works with other interrupts. I activate lower priority interrupt from higher priority interrupt, finish the higher priority interrupt and then enter the lower priority interrupt handler. But it doesn't work with SVC. SVC works if and only if its priority is higher than whatever its called from.

Is this expected behavior for SVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour.  If you want to pend a handler from within another handler, that's exactly what `PendSV` is designed for (see [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0646/b/BABBGBEC)) which is triggered by setting a bit in the ICSR (see [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0646/b/Cortex-M7-Peripherals/System-control-block/Interrupt-Control-and-State-Register?lang=en)).

`PendSV` is typically used for things like operating system context switches, which can then be guaranteed non-reentrant and can be multiply triggered without issue.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. PendSV is already taken in this regard, kicked off by the timer. I utilize extra pair of software interrupts which call one another, it's not like one needs all 90+ of them. Will have to come up with alternative design for system calls, but I don't think it should be a problem.

Comment: Interestingly enough, neither of the links you provided says anything about SVCall unusable if triggered from higher priority interrupt (I'm also already familiar with those pages)